# Fail on any usage of floating point

Tags: python

My python program manipulates bitcoin amounts precise to 8 decimal places. My intention is to use `decimal.Decimal` types everywhere, to avoid any floating point precision issues -- but I'm not sure I got every usage.

For quality assurance, I'd like to raise an error if there's any floats constructed anywhere in the program. Is this possible in python 3.5?

(I cannot use integers because I'm interfacing via JSON with other programs that expect decimal values.)

Comment: You can't monkey-patch built-ins (such as `float`), so you can't get notified when a `float` is `__init__`ialised. You can try using/writing a static code analyser. Have a look at `bandit` and see if you can write a custom plugin for it.

Comment: Setting an appropriate breakpoint inside the interpreter might suffice. Of course, you'd need to be able to ignore calls that are initialized from code that you don't want the audit to extend to (standard-library functions, etc).

Comment: You're probably better off doing this the other way around: create your own type that inherits from or wraps a `Decimal`, and disable any methods that allow combining it with a `float`.

Comment: Effectively, it would require overriding the `__init__` of the float type, but if you try this, Python will tell you `can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'float'`, so I suspect the answer is 'no'. You won't be able to catch instances like `x = 1.2`. Defining a new type called `float` also doesn't do the trick, Python won't use your type instead.